# Firebase auth getUser multiple users

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm successfully executing the [getUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) from auth. The problem comes when I need to retrieve the data of n users.

Is it possible without having to launch this function n times and avoiding the usage of [listUsers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  If you have a use case that requires this, please file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) explaining why the existing API doesn't meet you needs.